# Does TimeMachine has an higher priority than the sleep delay?

Tags: time-machine

When a long backup will soon occur or is running, will it go on and end even if the enter-sleep-mode settings is foreseen earlier?

Comment: Most Macs made since 2011 feature "Power Nap" mode, which will allow Time Machine to run while the machine is sleeping. On machines made prior to 2011 I am unsure.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sleep assertion for Time Machine. So while doing a backup your mac won't enter sleep mode. If you are not sure, while a backup is in progress, check with this command: `pmset -g assertions`. In the processes that prevent sleep mode you will found: `BackgroundTask named: "Time Machine backup"`